# C++ How to identify SIGNAL 11 error location

Tags: c++, linux

I´m running a multi-threaded C++ program in a Linux system 
(Kernel 2.6.23). My code is compiled using G++ version 4.7.4.

I added the following code to catch segmentation faults:

```
void segFaultHandler(int sig)
{
  void *array[10];
  size_t size;

  size = backtrace(array, 10);
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
  backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
  exit(1);
}
```

And on main:

```
main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, segFaultHandler);

    try {

         program code here...

    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown failure occurred. Possible memory corruption" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When running, my program is crashing with the following output:

```
Error: signal 11:
/home/cross/bin/aeirtu[0x807406e]
[0xffffe420]
/lib/libc.so.6(memcpy+0x2f)[0xb7d9bcbf]
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6xsputnEPKci+0x73)[0xb7f26933]
```

It is not a easy debug as my program crashes only sometimes, so I need a tool to get the crash source and fix it.

From the given output, how can I trace back the function and piece of code that caused the crash ?

Comment: Can you post your code?  It looks like it's failing in a `memcpy` call from the standard library.

Comment: First, remove your signal handler. Second, set up your system to produce core files. Third, use a debugger on a core file. It helps if you build with debugging information, and with no optimizations.

Comment: Anon, the code has tons of lines... That´s why I need the crash traceback.

Comment: n.m.: Can I have the signal handler and core files together, or are they mutual exclusive ?

Comment: You can't open the core file with gdb and get the exact point it crashed? Don't see the need for the signal handler if you can generate a core file. The core file will contain all the information you are trying to print out.

Comment: The core file contains the traceback and much more. In fact it contains a snapshot of the process memory at the moment of the crash. A debugger such as gdb will let you examine all aspects of the state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to locate the source of a segfault. If you binary is compiled with debug symbols it will give you the exact source location:

```
==12834== Invalid write of size 4
==12834==    at 0x4004FD: main (test.cc:3)
==12834==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Address Sanitizer (ASAN)](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) by google to detect segmentation faults as well as other common programming errors related to memory (including heap use after free, buffer overflow, buffer underflow, freeing memory twice, memory leaks, etc). If an error is detected, it will give a stack trace of exactly where the error occurred (and if you use -g to include debug symbols, the stack trace is fairly understandable).

ASAN gets linked into your binary at compile time and checks your heap at run time with very little overhead (code runs about 2x slower). This is significantly faster than valgrind and has the advantage that it can run in a live environment and give valuable messages if a 2x slow down is acceptable for your use case.

Furthermore, if your segmentation fault is caused by one of the aforementioned programming errors, it will be caught by ASAN before the code even seg faults. For example, let's say you buffer overflow, corrupting the state of the heap. When you go to malloc memory later, malloc seg faults because the heap is corrupted. Any signal handler would detect the corruption at this point, even though the real problem was a heap buffer overflow. ASAN would give you a stack trace at the time of heap buffer overflow.